# Переименовывание сессий

Tags: php

Пытаюсь задать сессии определённое значение, но когда перехожу по страницам сайта значение опять сбрасывается на дефолтное, помогите, пожалуйста понять, почему.
В файле `f1.php` сначала из БД получается значение `id` и сохраняется в `$_SESSION['id']`, а потом вызывается

```
require 'f2.php';
abc();
```

Написала вот такую функцию, которая находится в файле `f2.php`:

```
function abc() {
    $prefix = $_SESSION['id'];
    session_name('MYPROJECT'.($prefix ? '_'.$prefix : ''));
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
    echo "Имя сессии".session_name();
}
```

Вот здесь "Имя сессии": `MYPROJECT_1`

Далее нажимается кнопка, которая находится в файле `f1.php` (переход на другую страницу) и вызывается `f3.php` (в котором находится скрипт следующей страницы), и при вызове в этом файле `session_name()` имя сессии опять дефолтное

---

Опять ничего не получается.. Перепробовала уже уйму способов, но ничего не меняется. Сценарий такой: захожу под первым пользователем, логинюсь, открываю сайт для второго пользователя, логинюсь, потом возвращаюсь на первую вкладку (с 1м юзером) и при попытке перейти с этой вкладки на другую страницу сайта логин юзера меняется на последнего вошедшего (т.е второго). Не получается реализовать работу в разных вкладках под разными пользователями, они постоянно склеиваются в одного пользователя. 
Попробовала сделать так, как мне посоветовали здесь (на каждой странице сайта меняю имя сессии), но возникла проблема с $_SESSION['id'], которую использую для переименовывания, оно заменяется последней и не получается её сохранять, а поскольку данные авторизации получаются один раз, то постоянно делать запросы к БД тоже не могу, т.к переменные логин/пароль так же затираются

Последний код:

f1.php

```
session_start();
......   //подключение к БД
    $Login=$_POST['Login'];
    $Password=$_POST['Password'];
    $query="SELECT id
        FROM user
        WHERE login='".$Login."' AND password='".$Password."'";
       $zapros=mysql_query($query);
session_name('MYPROJECT'.($user['idemployee'] ? '_'.$user['idemployee']:''));
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user['idemployee'];
include "f2.php";
echo "Авторизация ";
```

f2.php

```
session_start();
if (session_id() ) {echo "Сессия создана с номером ".session_name();
 session_name('MYPROJECT'.($SESSION['id'] ? ''.$_SESSION['id'] : ''));
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
}
```

Comment: Может быть не хватает `session_start` http://www.php.su/session_start

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо устанавливать session_name при каждой загрузке приложения (старте сессии) к примеру:

```
start_session();
$prefix = $_SESSION['id'];
session_name('MYPROJECT'.($prefix ? '_'.$prefix : ''));
```

Перед каждым скриптом.

ps. зачем вам $prefix?

Comment: $prefix остался после множетва переделок кода, просто не убрала

Comment: т.е на каждой странице (в каждом .php файле) мне нужно будет переименовывать сессию, если организую это в виде функции и запишу в файл в котором кроме этой функции есть ещё куча другого кода, в том числе и html код, можно ли как-то вызывать только эту одну функцию (без другого кода, включая html) или лучше для этой функции создать отдельный файл?

Comment: @StPeLka да как удобнее можно и функцию написать в отдельном файле и подгружать его. тут как вам удобнее. Про html не стоит. точнее не стоит его мешать с php.

Answer (score 1):

session_name() должна вызывтся на всех страницах перед session_start() и session_register() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-name.php

Comment: только если session.name требуется изменить

Comment: @Etki А разве не это ТС хочет сделать ?

Comment: если честно, не знаю, я мимокрокодил и посчитал ответ слишком категоричным